# How do I find information of an instance in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I can see data constructor and instances for, say `Maybe` in ghci:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :i Maybe
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a     -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
instance Functor Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
instance Read a => Read (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
instance Applicative Maybe -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Alternative Maybe -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
```

and I can see how `Applicative` typeclass defined in ghci, too:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :i Applicative
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
  (<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
    -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Applicative [] -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Applicative ZipList -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Monad m => Applicative (WrappedMonad m)
  -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Applicative Maybe -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Applicative IO -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Applicative (Either e) -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
```

but How can I find information *about specific instances* of a type, say `instance Alternative Maybe` ?

Comment: I don't think you're able to pull up the actual code because GHCi simply might not have access to it. What would you like to see exactly?

Comment: @jozefg to see how haskell guys implemented that interface?

Comment: Not purely in GHCi but for local searching `cabal get base` will give you a copy of the sources of the latest version of the standard libraries and search with grep (line 685 of GHC/Base.hs for `instance Alternative Maybe`). However GHCi works only with various compiled representations of the code and so you won't have much luck asking it to print the source to an instance sadly.

Comment: Alternatively, there's a "view source" link on Haddock's for Haskell libraries which I make heavy use of. It now even has not-awful-looking syntax highlighting :) It's also usable in something like w3m if you use emacs.

Answer (score 4):

`ghci` doesn't have any commands that bring up the underlying source for functions and instances, although it would be neat if it did.

The way I find source of such things is to find them on hackage (for things in `base`, hoogle is the way to go). Then the haddocks [include links to source from the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Maybe).